# Capitalization of "guest of honor"

Tags: capitalization

In the following sentence, should *guest of honour* be capitalized?

> Ms. Joe Doe (DTM), the District Governor of Toastmasters International was the **Guest of Honour** during the charter party on March 23, 2008.

It looks a bit weird to me, and I am trying to find something that will support writing it (or not) this way.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Particularly if it was written by/for someone/some organisation wishing to elevate the status of the event and/or individuals involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about guests of honor in general, it definitely should be lowercase. However, as in your example, if you are talking about a specific guest of honor on a specific occasion, it could count as what Wikipedia calls a [specific designator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Specific_designators), so grammatically either way should be acceptable. However, looking at [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guest+of+honor%2C+Guest+of+Honor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to determine usage, it generally seems not to be capitalized.

[image]

Comment: cool, never heard about Ngrams. So does that mean that the majority of people is wrong or that capitalizing/specific designator is a fairly new trend?

Comment: Wikipedia says that deciding whether something counts as a specific designator for the purposes of capitalization *"is somewhat arbitrary, which is to say, individuals can make different choices without either one being 'wrong'".* So I'd say both decisions are grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the phrase has been capitalized to emphasize the status in which the person was present.

If Ms. Joe Doe (DTM), was the **District Governor** of *Toastmasters International*, 
she was also 
the **Guest of Honour** at the *charter party*.

It seems customary to mention of the **Chairperson** or **Chief Guest** at (of) a meeting.